# Console Errors NodeJS configuration

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket, async.js

I will make a realtime chat for an android app, I'm thinking about using NodeJS and websockets, but I have not used this technology before, and I'm having some troubles to start with it

I've already installed nodejs from console (I'm using Archlinux)

when I start my index.js the console (in sublime text) throws this Error log:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'jsc'
[cmd: ['jsc', '/srv/http/NodeJsApplication/index.js']]
[dir: /srv/http/NodeJsApplication]
[path: /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl]
[Finished]
```

The package.json file looks like this:

```
 {
  "name": "nodejsapplication",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "NodeJS chat for Android application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "index.js",
    "test": "make test"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "nodejs",
    "npm",
    "chat_application"
  ],
  "author": "JProg",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

I've already install express and NodeJS

I have not experience with this technology.

Here is the code of index.js

```
    const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    res.statusCode=200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Hola mundo\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, ()=>
    console.log('Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}');
    );
```

Comment: can you add what is inside `index.js` ?

Comment: I've added it, I'd forgot it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be with you installation of node.
Check if you can `node --version`.

Also in your package.json under `scripts` => `"start": "node index.js"`.
Are you using any IDE to run the app from it, if so check if it can find the path of node.

Comment: I'm using only Sublime Text and with the command node --version i got: v10.0.0 I used the console to create the project.

Comment: Try to run it from command line (from root directory run => `npm start`) and also check if its installed properly.
I.e `node --version`

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to reinstall NodeJS and create the project again.
I also had some mistakes in my code, here are the changes I did:

```
    "scripts": {
    "test": "make test", 
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
```

And the index.js

```
var port = 8080;
var hostname = 'localhost';
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(port, hostname, 500, function(){
    console.log('Executing server on http://localhost:8080');
});
```

Now It's woking